Problems detecting Camera on Raspberry PI 5 , with Ubuntu 24.10
I just installed the latest Ubuntu 24.10 on my Raspberry PI 5, 8GB with a HQ IMX477 camera connected to one of the MIPI connectors
I first tried using v4l2 , without finding the camera:
mh@PI5:~/src/rpicam-apps$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.

I have edited the configure.txt with dtoverlay=imx477 as described in various places. Also disabled the autodetect of camera.
I then build from source the libcamera and rpicam-apps from source, but same results there:
mh@PI5:~/src/rpicam-apps$ rpicam-hello
Could not open any dmaHeap device
[0:22:06.896145411] [5467]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:325 libcamera v0.3.2+28-b55eb33e
Preview window unavailable
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***

Also the cam function in libcamera showed nothing:
mh@PI5:~/src/rpicam-apps$ cam -l
[0:35:47.471930086] [5994]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:325 libcamera v0.3.2+28-b55eb33e
Available cameras:
mh@PI5:~/src/rpicam-apps$ 

I feel a little bit stuck now, so if anyone has made camera working on RPI-5 with latest Ubuntu 24.10, I would be happy to know how you did it.
Thanks,
Martin
